# How to make ''turn page'' button in standalone class?

Tags: tikz-node

I'd like to make a ''turn page'' button with `node` in standalone in the `tikzpicture` environment, for example, there're 3 `tikzpicture` environments in a standalone class, and there will certainly generate 3 'pages' in the PDF document. I want to insert a button with `node` on every page, click the button can turn to the next page while click the button on the last page can return to the first page, how can I reach this?

Comment: You can use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` (hyperref package) but you have to put them inside the tikzpictures.  Either that or replace [tiks] with [multi=minipage] etc.